# Combine Array of Objects with similar keys conditionally using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like :

```
const data = [
    {
        day: 'monday',
        time: '10:00 AM',
        type: 'start',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'monday',
        time: '11:30 AM',
        type: 'end',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'tuesday',
        time: '01:00 PM',
        type: 'start',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'tuesday',
        time: '06:00 PM',
        type: 'end',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'wednesday',
        time: '10:00 AM',
        type: 'start',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'wednesday',
        time: '06:00 PM',
        type: 'end',
        unit: 1
    }
];
```

I need to combine two objects with same `'day'` key (for ex.`day:'monday'` )into one where if object contains `type: 'start'` then it will be `'start_time': '10:00 AM'` in the new object and if `'type': 'end'` then it will be `'end_time': 11:30 AM` in the new object. `sr_no` starts with 1 and is incremented by 1. It(array of new objects) should look something like this:

```
 var newArray = [    
        {
            sr_no: 1,
            day: 'monday',
            start_time: '10:00 AM',
            end_time: '11:30 AM',
            unit: 1
        },
        {
            sr_no: 2,
            day: 'tuesday',
            start_time: '01:00 PM',
            end_time: '06:00 PM',
            unit: 1
        },
        {
            sr_no: 3,
            day: 'wednesday',
            start_time: '10:00 AM',
            end_time: '06:00 PM',
            unit: 1
        }
];
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what difficulties did you have with your attempts?

Comment: are they always ordered like this, if so you could just merge data[i] and data[i+1] then i+=2

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I tried using reduce to parse using current value and next value but it would not construct an object like i want `data.reduce(function(prev, curr){
        if(prev.day === curr.day) {
            output.day = prev.day;
            output.start_time = prev.time;
            output.end_time = curr.time;
            output.unit = prev.unit;
        }
             
    })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to aggregate the data by day and  [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with  [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to format it to the desired output:

```js
const data=[{day:'monday',time:'10:00 AM',type:'start',unit:1},{day:'monday',time:'11:30 AM',type:'end',unit:1},{day:'tuesday',time:'01:00 PM',type:'start',unit:1},{day:'tuesday',time:'06:00 PM',type:'end',unit:1},{day:'wednesday',time:'10:00 AM',type:'start',unit:1},{day:'wednesday',time:'06:00 PM',type:'end',unit:1}];


const grouped = data.reduce((all, {day, time, type, unit}) => {

  if (!all.hasOwnProperty(day)) all[day] = { day, unit };

  all[day][`${type}_time`] = time;

  return all;

}, {});

const result = Object.keys(grouped).map((a,i) => ({sr_no: i + 1, ...grouped[a]}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to transform the data to what you need, though how your `sr_no` is determined is not entirely clear.

```js
const data = [
    {
        day: 'monday',
        time: '10:00 AM',
        type: 'start',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'monday',
        time: '11:30 AM',
        type: 'end',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'tuesday',
        time: '01:00 PM',
        type: 'start',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'tuesday',
        time: '06:00 PM',
        type: 'end',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'wednesday',
        time: '10:00 AM',
        type: 'start',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'wednesday',
        time: '06:00 PM',
        type: 'end',
        unit: 1
    }
];


const transform = input => input
  .map(dayData => dayData.day)
  .map(day => input.filter(dayData => dayData.day === day))
  .map(bothTimes => ({
    day: bothTimes[0].day,
    start_time: bothTimes.filter(dayData => dayData.type === 'start')[0].time,
    end_time: bothTimes.filter(dayData => dayData.type === 'end')[0].time,
    unit: bothTimes[0].unit
  }))
  
const result = transform(data)
console.dir(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your datas will always be sorted so one day is always next to the same, you can easily go with one good old for loop:

```
const newArray = [];

for (let i = 0, n = 1; i < data.length; i += 2, n++) {
  const sr_no = n;
  const day = data[i].day;
  const start_time = data[i].type === 'start' ? data[i].time : data[i + 1].time;
  const end_time = data[i].type === 'end' ? data[i].time : data[i + 1].time;
  const unit = data[i].unit;

  newArray.push({
    sr_no,
    day,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    unit
  });
}
```

If your datas are not sorted to use this kind of loop, then just sort it before using a good `sort()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Calculates the correct sr_no according to your output.

```js
const data = [
    {
        day: 'monday',
        time: '10:00 AM',
        type: 'start',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'monday',
        time: '11:30 AM',
        type: 'end',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'tuesday',
        time: '01:00 PM',
        type: 'start',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'tuesday',
        time: '06:00 PM',
        type: 'end',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'wednesday',
        time: '10:00 AM',
        type: 'start',
        unit: 1
    },
    {
        day: 'wednesday',
        time: '06:00 PM',
        type: 'end',
        unit: 1
    }
];

const update = (arr)=>{
   const x = {}
   
   const constructObj = (item,indx)=>{
       const original = x[item.day] || {};
       const key = item.type === 'start'? 'start_time':'end_time';
       original.sr_no = Object.keys(x).indexOf(item.day)+1;
       original[key] = item.time;
       original.unit = item.unit;
       return original;
   }
  
   arr.forEach((item,indx)=>{
       x[item.day] = constructObj(item,indx);
   })
  
   return x;
}

console.log(update(data));
```